# Write Object[] in parquet file

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

To write some csv data into parquet I can use Spark SQL. I write simple code like this:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType schema = getSchema();
List<Object[]> data = getData();
List<Row> rows = data.stream().map(RowFactory::create).collect(Collectors.toList());
sparkSession.createDataFrame(rows, schema).write().parquet(path);
```

But now I need to do that without spark. I have `org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType` schema. And I found library `org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:1.11.0` (https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.parquet/parquet-hadoop/1.11.0/index.html). In this library, class `ParquetWriter` is used to write data. To do that it has method write(T object) and required object of class `WriteSupport<T>` (with metadata), where T - data type to write.

I have two questions about this class:

1. How can I simply convert org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType schema to WriteSupport.
2. How can I simply convert Row or Object[] to type T and how to define its type?

P.S.: I read about writing with Avro format and classes, but this is not what I want.